# Why do I get "conflicting implementations of trait" for f32 which does not implement Ord?

Tags: rust

I want a `min()` method for `f32`, `u32` and `i32`, so I created a trait `Min`:

```
trait Min {
    fn min(v1: Self, v2: Self) -> Self;
}

impl<T> Min for T where T: Ord {
    fn min(v1: Self, v2: Self) -> Self {
        ::std::cmp::min(v1, v2)
    }
}

impl Min for f32 {
    fn min(v1: Self, v2: Self) -> Self {
        v1.min(v2)
    }
}
```

I get an error:

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `Min` for type `f32`:
  --> src/main.rs:11:1
   |
5  | / impl<T> Min for T where T: Ord {
6  | |     fn min(v1: Self, v2: Self) -> Self {
7  | |         ::std::cmp::min(v1, v2)
8  | |     }
9  | | }
   | |_- first implementation here
10 | 
11 | / impl Min for f32 {
12 | |     fn min(v1: Self, v2: Self) -> Self {
13 | |         v1.min(v2)
14 | |     }
15 | | }
   | |_^ conflicting implementation for `f32`
```

According to the Rust standard library documentation, `f32` does not implement `Ord`. Why there are conflicting implementations?

Comment: @erip  It seems [`f32`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.f32.html) only implements `PartialOrd`

Comment: Wow, this seems like a bug. With only the generic implementation, the compiler clearly says that f32 does not implement Ord, but in the OP's example, it considers that f32 implements the generic one.

Comment: @Laurence Woops. :) Thanks for keeping me honest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is because the compiler can't rule out the possibility that someday, someone *will* implement `Ord` for `f32`.  To put it another way: if the compiler *didn't* act conservatively, it would be a breaking change to ever implement *any* new trait on existing types.  That would severely limit every library's ability to grow without breaking all downstream users.

There is no direct way around this, as it is an intentional design choice for the language.  The closest would be to implement a wrapper type *around* `f32` (*i.e.* `struct OrdF32(f32);`) and implement `Ord` or `Min` on *that*, or to use a crate that defines such a wrapper (such as [`ordered-float`](https://crates.io/crates/ordered-float)).

Comment: How to get around it?

Comment: @Boiethios: You don't; I added some more to my answer.

Comment: @Laurence: The closest I'm aware of is [RFC 1023](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1023-rebalancing-coherence.md), but if that proves too inscrutable, then I'm not aware of anything that explains it more... *coherently*.

Comment: @Laurence these are called the *orphan rules*, IIRC. Refer to [RFC 1023](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1023-rebalancing-coherence.md) and [error 0210](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0210).

Comment: Can this be side-stepped by implementing `Ord` for `f32`?

Comment: @9000: You *can't* implement `Ord` for `f32`, because it doesn't satisfy the requirements: it's not totally ordered.  Even if it did, you can't, because you can't implement a trait you didn't write on a type you didn't define.

Comment: With [specialization](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1210-impl-specialization.md) in mind, do you think this can be worked around somehow?